# Req.body gets undefined in node using express

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I am using the express . 

Here is my code i tried , In *user.controller* , i am getting undefined.  
**index.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const cors = require('cors');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    const app = express();

    //import route
    const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');

    //use express function
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // commenting this line also did not worked
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // commenting this line also did not worked
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    app.use('/user' , userRoutes);
```

**user.js (router)**

```
const express = require('express');
const userController = require('../controller/user.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/signUp' , userController.signUp);

module.exports = router;
```

**user.controller.js**

```
const userModel = require('../models/user.model');
var userController = {};

userController.signUp = function(req, res){
    console.log("it works ======>" , req.body); // here i m getting undefined .
}

module.exports = userController;
```

Here is my body i am send from *postman* 
[image]

Here is my headers .[image]

I Have gone through all the SO link and tried all the ways but that didn't did the trick therefore i ask separately .

I am not getting this weird behaviour .

Comment: Can you show what headers are getting set in Postmen?

Comment: I am not sending header . I have unmark the header . @Ejaz47

Comment: The image of postman you provided showing headers(10).

Comment: OK let me show my header too . @Ejaz47

Comment: Updated my code . You can checkout @Ejaz47

Comment: Note that instead of checking in postman, you can log the headers received via ```console.log(req.headers)```. That said, __if__ you are sending json, have you tried to send the header:```'Content-Type': 'application/json'```

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama, The problem is in your code order,  You need to use `const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');` after  `app.use(bodyParser.json());`.

Comment: in postman headers, why did you unchecked the  `Content-Type: application/json` ?
Can you check it and try?

Comment: @Ejaz47 - That's not correct.  They can `require()` in the route whenever they want.  It's when the router gets put in `app.use()` that matters and that's already at the end.

Comment: @jfriend00, Yes you are right, I was miss understood the code.

Comment: This is very weird behaviour . @jfriend00

Comment: It seems likely that you're just not sending the appropriate format of a request from postman.  It would be nice if you could see the EXACT raw request that was going out from postman or coming into Express because it seems like there's a 98% chance the reason `req.body` is `undefined` is that the request doesn't match the right settings to get parsed by your middleware.  I don't know postman myself to know what its settings mean.  That's why I want to see the actual request.

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama, I can see in your first image the response in postman is 500 Internal server error. That can be a possible reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

In postman body options, when you choose raw and JSON postman automatically adds `Content-Type: application/json` header.  But you seem to uncheck that header.

Postman does not send the headers, which are unchecked. So you cannot access the request body in the express side.

It will work when you check (select) that header and try.

Also there is no need install and use `body-parser` package if you use express version 4.16+.

Comment: i also tried using unchecked the header and also by installing `body-parser` . But that not worked .

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama  as I said in the answer, `Content-Type: application/json`  must be checked .

Comment: Friend , i tried by both the  ways . By doing checked and unchecked .

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama ok, it must be always checked,  and also in body options raw and JSON option. Lastly remove the body-parser related codes, and just use   app.use(express.json());

Answer (score 0):

Your last middleware overwrites the correct setting.

```
...
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Good
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // Bad, above line has been disabled.
...
```

If you are using express with version > 4.x , you can use the built-in middleware function in [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded) instead of `body-parser` (it is the same).

Your index.js file will come to:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const cors = require('cors');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    const app = express();

    //import route
    const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');

    //use express function
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    // app.use(bodyParser.json()); // remove
    // app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // remove 
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // `true` instead of `false` 

    app.use('/user' , userRoutes);
```